# jQuery - selector inside another selector - passed in variable loses its value and becomes an indexer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

I'm somewhat new to jQuery and am just wondering how I go about passing in a string value rather than what appears to be a reference to a jQuery item from a selector?  I'm having a hard time explaining so here's a sample demo.  Don't even know what to title this so please have at editing the title if you can think of a better one.

At the line where I do `$("td").filter(function(str){`  the str that is passed in becomes an index position of which TD I'm in. So while debugging the first time in it's a 0 the next time a 1 and so on.  I tried google but I'm not even sure what to search for, any documentation/code help would be much appreciated

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name='showTeam']").change(function () {
            $("select[name='showTeam'] option:selected").each(function () {
                var str = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                //str = what it was set to up there
                //alert(str);
                $("td").filter(function(str) {
                    //str = becomes a number = to position of TD.. ie for 5th TD match STR = 4 (starts at index 0)
                    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(str) != -1;
            }).css('background','red');
        });
    })
});
</script>
Show Team: <select id="showTeam" name="showTeam">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>Chelsea</option>
    </select>

<div id="games">
  <table border="1">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Game date</th>
    <th>Field</th>
    <th>Home team</th>
    <th>Home team score</th>
    <th>Away team</th>
    <th>Away team score</th>
    <th>Game type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd_line" id="game_460">
    <td>459</td>
    <td>03 Nov 19:00</td>
    <td>Field 2</td>
    <td>Madrid </td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Bayern Munich </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Season</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd_line" id="game_461">
    <td>460</td>
    <td>03 Nov 19:00</td>
    <td>Field 3</td>
    <td>chelsea</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>arsenal</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Season</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: [Documentation on `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: ugh I don't know how I missed that, I guess I have to rethink my approach.. thanks

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? What are you intending to achieve with the `filter()` method?

Comment: Looking to hide rows that do not have a team name (ie: chelsea) in one of their cells.  Using this example, on drop down selection change, use that value to highlite (background: red) any td which contains that select value

Comment: You may want to just revise your question.  You'll have more room and have an easier time formatting it.  Just add it to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showTeam").change(function () {
        var searchFor = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#games table tbody tr td:contains('" + searchFor + "')").parent().css('background','red');
    })
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zRANZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. The first parameter will refer to the index of the element in the set of matched elements. Just do:

```
...
$("select[name='showTeam'] option:selected").each(function() {
    var str = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("td").filter(function() {

        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(str) != -1;
    }).css('background', 'red');​
    ...
```

since `str` will already be available within the scope of the `filter` callback function.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> **.filter( function(index) )**
>
> function(index)A function used as a test for each element in the set.
>   this is the current DOM element.

Comment: Thank you, I see you've changed this to use .each instead of .change so it no longer fires on select item change.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @BrianGarson - Huh? No, I just posted enough that you could see what I changed easily. That's not a rewrite of your code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showTeam").change(function() {
        var target = $("#showTeam").val();
        $("#games td:contains(" + target + ")").css('background','red');
    });
});
```

I've made a jsfiddle to demonstrate this.
http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5dA/

Notes:
`:contains()` is case sensitive so I had to make "Chelsea" capitalized in the table.
I simplified the selector on the select element - it has an id, so I selected that.  Faster and simpler.
This will find `td` cells that *contain* the text, but they can also contain other text.  This will get you started.